# Append dataframe on a existing dataframe in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make an app that according to the selection of the user will subsetting the dataframe of the data. After that I want to create a new dataframe with unique values of col1 abd and the new dataframes added as new columns to the existing dataframe depending on users choice (like from a long shape of the dates making them in wide).
Any thoughts??? 
my dataset is that

```
col1<-rep(c(1:4),3)
col2<-c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c')
col3<-c(1,2,3,NA,NA,14,15,NA,NA,20,21,22)
col4<-c(NA,NA,1,2,3,14,15,20,21,22,NA,NA)
df<-data.table(col1,col2,col3,col4)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   selectInput('Ind', 'Index',choices = c(unique(df$col2))),
   dataTableOutput('Table')
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {



 dfsel<-reactive({dfnew<-subset(df,col2==input$Ind)
 dfnew
 })
 output$Table<-renderDataTable(dfsel())

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

what ia am trying to achive is when first the user selects 'a'

the results to be this

```
 col1   col2    col3    col4
    1    a       1  
    2    a      20      22
    3    a      15      15
    4    a               2
```

Then if the user selects c the new dataframe will be

```
 col1   col2    col3    col4    col2    col3    col4
    1    a       1                c               21
    2    a      20      22        c      14       14
    3    a      15      15        c       3       1
    4    a               2        c      22
```

and so on

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: I want to in the dataset dfsel which I create insert each time the user choose another input append the corresping subset on the dfsel. One problem is that the column names are the same and I cant just append them so how reactivly can I change the column names and append the new values?

Comment: You want to add rows to the displayed table as the user selects subsets?

Comment: To add columns actually

Comment: Please try and explain yourself more carefully. Maybe you need a diagram. It is not clear if you are talking about rows or columns.

Comment: @MikeWise I tried to explain the best I could. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you want. This does it I believe.

I made the following changes to your example

- added a new datatable (`rv$dfnew`) as reactiveValues to keep track of our data table as it grows
- Changed the display to show the currently selected part of the data frame as well as the growing `dfnew` table
- Added a count variable that is appended to the columns as we proceed to keep them all unique.
- Added an actionButton `doAppendCols` to append the columns.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
col1<-rep(c(1:4),3)

col2<-c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c')
col3<-c(1,2,3,NA,NA,14,15,NA,NA,20,21,22)
col4<-c(NA,NA,1,2,3,14,15,20,21,22,NA,NA)
df<-data.table(col1,col2,col3,col4)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Append Columns"),

  selectInput('Ind', 'Index',choices = c(unique(df$col2))),
  actionButton("doAppendCols","Append Columns"),
  h2("Selected Data"),
  dataTableOutput('selTable'),
  h2("New Table"),
  dataTableOutput('newTable')
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(dfnew=NULL,count=0)

  observeEvent(input$doAppendCols,{
    rv$count <- rv$count+1
    dfs <- dfsel()
    # add a running number as suffix to column names to make the columns unique
    newsuffix <- paste0(".",rv$count)
    ncols <- ncol(dfs)
    names(dfs)[2:ncols] <- paste0( names(dfs)[2:ncols],newsuffix )
    if(is.null(rv$dfnew)){
      rv$dfnew <- dfs
    } else {
      rv$dfnew <- merge(rv$dfnew,dfs,by="col1")
    }
  })

  dfsel<-reactive({
    df<-subset(df,col2==input$Ind)
    df <- df[order(df$col1),]
  })
  output$selTable<-renderDataTable(dfsel())
  output$newTable<-renderDataTable(rv$dfnew)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here is the sample output:

[image]

Comment: thank you!!! yeas that was exacly what I was trying to do and I had problem with the name of the columns! thank you!!!